# MySQL query that checks that the logged in user has access to the content? (where the content belongs to a class where the user is enrolled in)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a theoretical issue, that I need to translate it to a database query in MySQL.

I have students that can be enrolled into a class. Each class have some class lectures (content). **Only students enrolled in the class should be able to access the lectures assigned to that class.** Each lecture could be assigned to N classes.

I have several tables:

USERS table with the `userID` field.

CONTENT table with `contentID` field.

CLASS table with the `classID` field.

USERS-CLASSES table with the `userID` and the `classID` fields

CONTENTS-CLASSES table with the `classID` and `contentID` fields.

**I have no idea on how the query should actually be formulated** to check that the user ID of the logged in user is connected with the classID of the class to which the lecture that the user wants to read belongs to (the content).

Any clue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lecture? What lecture. It does not apear in the schema you showed us. Nor have you explained how "enrolled" is represented in the schema.

Comment: Right, you didn't state how the entity *lecture* is described in this schema or what relationship it has with users and classes.

Comment: SELECT (1) ex FROM `USERS-CLASSES` uc INNER JOIN `CONTENTS-CLASSES` cc ON cc.classID = uc.classID WHERE uc.userID = X ???

Comment: Sorry, I did clarify it now, lecture is the content.

Answer (score 0):

This can be completed with a simple [INNER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

```
SELECT 1 FROM USERS-CLASSES uc
INNER JOIN CONTENTS-CLASSES cc ON cc.classID = uc.classID
WHERE uc.userID = {userID}
```

If the query returns 1, they're authorized to view that content.

If you want to know for a userID **AND** classID, simply add it to your where.

```
SELECT 1 FROM USERS-CLASSES uc
INNER JOIN CONTENTS-CLASSES cc ON cc.classID = uc.classID
WHERE uc.userID = {userID}
AND uc.classID = {classID}
```